# Stored procedure - why duplicate code paths! Query hint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012

I have a working fast stored procedure called using these 2 scenarios

```
exec GetResults
      @SDate=N'15/90/2015', @EDate=N'22/09/2015', 
      @DateTimeOfEventStart=default, @DateTimeOfEventEnd=default

exec GetResults
     @SDate=default, @EDate=default, 
     @DateTimeOfEventStart=N'15/90/2015', @DateTimeOfEventEnd=N'22/09/2015'
```

To make both queries fast I have had to split up the code path:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetResults
    @SDate varchar(20)=NULL,
    @EDate varchar(20)=NULL,
    @DateTimeOfEventStart varchar(20)=NULL,
    @DateTimeOfEventEnd varchar(20)=NULL
AS
    IF @DateTimeOfEventStart IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT ...
        WHERE
            (@SDate IS NULL OR (ImportTime>= (Convert(datetime,@SDate,105) + ' 00:00:00')))
            AND (@EDate IS NULL OR (ImportTime<= (Convert(datetime,@EDate,105) + ' 23:59:59')))
            AND (@DateTimeOfEventStart IS NULL OR (EventTime>= (Convert(datetime,@DateTimeOfEventStart,105) + ' 00:00:00')))
            AND (@DateTimeOfEventEnd IS NULL OR (EventTime<= (Convert(datetime,@DateTimeOfEventEnd,105) + ' 23:59:59')))
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT ... (exactly the same as above)
```

Using this strange method, both stored procedure calls work fast. It feels like there should be a better way. Possibly query hints, but nothing has jumped out.

Query time is around 500ms for each. Without this am looking at 2-4secs.. for either (depends which one I run first, with that being the fastest)

Comment: Although it probably does not affect performance, why are you passing date parameters in as characters rather than using `date`?

Comment: don't use this (Convert(datetime,@SDate,105) + ' 00:00:00'), (Convert(datetime,@EDate,105) + ' 23:59:59'), (Convert(datetime,@DateTimeOfEventStart,105) + ' 00:00:00') and (Convert(datetime,@DateTimeOfEventStart,105) + ' 23:59:59') in where clause declare in some variable and refer those variable in where clause. You can see some little difference then before.

Comment: The reason for passing varchars instead of dates is legacy code.  Point taken though thanks.  Regarding taking the convert out of the where.. good point too.

Comment: Engine ill detect the conditional and store a execution plan for each path, that way otimizing performance. This leads to a drop in the technique fo puting conditional in the **WHERE** and favor using **IF**